# How to count number of records in sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android project. I used sqlite database for it. I have tables in database. I have created databasehelper class. i want to count number of records in particular table. how can i achieve this ? any help will be appreciated?

Comment: Hope cursor length will help you.

Comment: `return db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM table", null).getCount();`

Answer (score 52):

This would be more efficient:

```
int numRows = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name", null);
```

Or:

```
int numRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "table_name");
```

Comment: They both don't work if you don't cast them to (int) since they return a long.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Your second answer is okay according to the Google documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, java.lang.String)

Use long instead of int. e.g.

long numRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "table_name");

Answer (score 17):

Using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` query and, than **count the size of Cursor**..

The method from Cursor to count size (number of rows in cursor) is,

```
getCount()
```

**Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor.**

**OR:**

From [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) use method `queryNumEntries(SQLiteDatabase db, String table)`

Like,

`long numberOfRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "table_name");`

which **returns the number of rows in the table**.

Comment: Is't the cursor always going to be 1... Don't you actually want to fetch the first record in the cursor and then look in index 0 for the count?

Comment: You can also pass selection arguments by using `DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries (SQLiteDatabase db, String table, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)` method.

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from your_table_name",null);
Log.i("Number of Records"," :: "+c.getCount());
```

**Edit :**  **c.getCount()** returns the number of records of particular table.

Comment: .getCount() is fine if you are getting the main data for another purpose but getting all of the data back just to count it is inefficient.  A rawQuery of "select count(*) from your_table_name" would be better as suggested by @Nick Bradbury

Comment: Why selecting all fields, you can select any one field. This is for Optimization.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin

```
fun getFruitTableCount(): Int {
        val db = readableDatabase
        val numRows = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DBContract.FruitEntry.TABLE_NAME, null).toInt()
        return numRows
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In your DatabaseHelper.java:

```
public Cursor getYourTableContents() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "Your table name", null);

  return data;
}
```

To get the number of rows in your table:

```
Cursor yourCursor = myDB.getYourTableContents();

int i = 0;

while (yourCursor.moveToNext()) {
  i += 1;
}
```

`i` is your rows count as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
In db handler class use this method

Kotlin Code :

fun getCount(): Int {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        var count= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME", null).count
        db.close()
        return count
    }

Then directly call getCount after creating an instance of db handler class
```